# Auto-Filtering List in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I'm looking for a way to filter a list in a gsp by entering a keyword in a textfield.
The filtering should not need a confirm action like return or pressing a button.

For example see the preference window in Eclipse.

I first thought jquery is the solution, but this also needs a confirmation to filter.

Is this possible with Grails?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use JavaScript to do this, so the question has little or nothing to do with Grails/GSPs.

There is no confirmation needed to perform the filtering if you listen to the `onchange` event of the user input field. If this input field has id `textBox` the code would look something like this:

```
$('#textBox').change(function() {
    var queryString = $(this).text();

    // Now get a reference to your list and filter out all entries that don't match
    // queryString
});
```

Comment: +1 - Also, most filtering lists I've seen use `onkeyup` for updates as you type, although when the datasource is remote that may not be quite ideal. The OP might be interested, though.